# Are lithium-ion battery cells' maximum discharge ratings based on heat?

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, temperature, discharge, battery-chemistry

For any given lithium-ion battery cell, would I be able to discharge more than its rated maximum discharge value provided that it's for a brief time and/or the heat does not rise up and be sustained by a certain amount?

Like for instance if I discharge a 10 A battery at 10.1 A for just one second, and stop for 100 seconds, and do it again repeatedly, would there be any long-term chemical damage?

Comment: What is a 10 A battery? Do you mean a 10 amp hours capacity? Or a battery rated with 10 A maximum current?

Comment: @Uwe OP says maximum discharge rating so 10A is probably synonymous to C-rating.

Comment: @Uwe A battery rated with 10A maximum current.

Comment: Low quality batteries that have too much rice inside produce low maximum current. Look at this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eOshOXcSkDA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general (not just batteries), you cannot increase the current and reduce the time interval ad infinitum because material construction is imperfect and non-homogenous and it takes time for heat generated to to spread out and equilibriate. Heat is produced instantaneously and unevenly in the material due to these imperfections and it takes time for the heat to travel and equilibrate across the material; Time which component does not have if you keep shortening the time interval and this will generate hot spots which will fail and the dominoes start falling from there.

And 1 second is an eternity in electricity and heat generation, but not heat transfer.

Also note the way ratings work. It's not a hard universal physical limit. All ratings are obtained under some set of criteria. This criteria includes what the designers have deemed as an acceptable compromise between wear/degradation and performance for size or mass for the expected application and operating environment. So if the battery was expected to be used in a colder or or windier environment the same battery might be rated for higher current than if it were expected to be used in a warmer or more enclosed enclosed environment. Or if the battery was intended for an application where it needed to be much more reliable or last through many more charge cycles the battery might be rated for a much lower current than a less critical, more disposable application. Yet, the battery might not be physically changed at all.

There is also variance between individual components which produces variances between the component under test used to obtain the rating and the actual component you have in hand. So 10A vs 10.1A is probably meaningless, whereas 10A vs 100A is not.

So, to answer your question about whether it causes long term damage/wear: It depends on how how conservative the rating criteria is relative to your intended usage, your criteria for acceptable wear/damage, and how close you are to that thermal generation vs time threshold. So in some cases you can push it, and in other cases you can push it more if you are willing to accept the increased wear. Applications that are disposable or run for short-time can push batteries especially hard for their size (torpedoes, missiles, etc).

Comment: Just for clarification, if I were to run a cell rated for a 10A continous discharge, it would eventually settle on a certain temperature throughout the entire cell. Then if I ran the same cell at a higher current than 10A, as long as I prevent its discharge when it approaches or reaches that same temperature, I would be expecting the same kind of wear-and-tear as implied by the 10A rating? (as implied by the battery cell designer)

Comment: @plu Dynamic heat always generation makes hot spots and the higher the change in heat generation the more intense the hot spot. There is average temperature over the entire volume/area of the battery and the local temperature at any single point in the battery, and they aren't the same. The shorter the time interval the more different they are, and the local temperature of the hottest spot is always higher than the overall temperature. You can't measure the temperature of these microscopic, internal hot spots. The question is are these hot spots too hot?

Comment: So if the battery equilibriates to be 40C at some steady state discharge current, and you increase the discharge current, somewhere in the battery will be hotter than 40C while the overall temperature is equilibriating even if you can't measure it. It doesn't matter if you run it shorter; That hot spot is always hotter. It's not as black/white in reality but I don't know enough to talk about local thermal capacity.

Comment: Thanks, the possibility of localized hotspots are helpful, to consider. // Looking into it further, I found a quick visulation into the idea of such hotpots with a battery under a pulse of current: "Analysis of Electro-Thermal Hot Spot Formation in Li-Ion-Battery-Cells", Fig. 12, https://www.comsol.com/paper/download/181677/beckert_paper.pdf